# How to manipulate time while fetching from SQL

Tags: php, mysql

One of my employers has requested that I fetch timestamps and return them, manipulated by a set user variable (their timezone)

What they want is for the users time zone (which is in this case a integer) to be added into the timestamp (either adding, subtracting, or not changing the original time); they are using GMT, if that helps.

```
$timezone = -4;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I' . -$timezone . ':%M %p", strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
}
```

This code should return the time stamp with the time adjusted, but instead just returns the $timezone variable in quotes (with the timestamp of course)

I have tried asking this question before but was recommended a different way of doing what I'm doing, but the problem is my employeer has demmanded I do it this way.  There has to be accomplish what I'm doing.  I have exhausted myself trying to figure this out.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace ' (quote) to " (double quote) in first strftime variable like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I" . -$timezone . ":%M %p", strtotime($row["timestamp"]));
}
```

this code gave you the $timezone variables value.